# Two inequalities involving distribuants and expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

I have to show that if $X \ge 0$ then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X \ge n) \le E[X] \le 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X \ge n).$$

I know that if the random variable $X$ takes only values in $\mathbb N$, we have:

$$E[X] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n P(X=n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^j P(X=k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty P(X = n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X \ge n)$$

How can I use this idea to prove my inequality

Comment: The same idea, just replace $P(X=n)$ by $P(n+1>X\geq n)$ and some of the equalities become inequalities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}E[X]&=\int XdP\\&=\sum_{n\geq0}\int_{n\leq X<n+1}XdP\\&\geq\sum_{n>0}\int_{n\leq X<n+1}ndP\\&=\sum_{n>0}nP(n\leq X<n+1)\\&=\sum_{n>0}P(X\geq n)\end{align}$$

The other side is similar.

$$\begin{align}E[X]&=\int XdP\\&=\sum_{n\geq0}\int_{n\leq X<n+1}XdP\\&\leq\sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{n\leq X<n+1}(n+1)dP\\&=\sum_{n>0}nP(n\leq X<n+1)+\sum_{n\geq0}P(n\leq X<n+1)\\&=1+\sum_{n>0}P(X\geq n)\end{align}$$

Comment: Tricky! During exercises we have solved it using another definition of expected value, $E[X] = \int_0^\infty P(X \ge t) \,\textrm{d}t$ (assuming $X \ge 0$).